# Shopify Missing Parameter ID

Tags: html, forms, shopify

I'm getting the error:

> Parameter Missing or Invalid: Required parameter missing or invalid:
>   id

When trying to add a product to the basket from the product page, don't understand why this is happening?

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% if product.options.size > 1 %}
        <fieldset class="group">
          <ul class="checkbox">
            {% for variant in product.variants %}
            {% if variant.available == true %}

                  <li>
                    <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="{{variant.id}}" name="id" />
                    {{ variant.title }} for {{ product.price | minus:variant.price | money_with_currency }}
                    </label>
                  </li>
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </fieldset>
        {% endif %}
            <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" class="inpost-buy w-button" value="Add to Bag →"></input>
      </form>
```

Any help to get this sorted would be brilliant!

EDIT - Updated Code

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post">
            {% if product.options.size > 1 %}
            <fieldset class="group">
              <ul class="checkbox">
              {% for variant in product.variants %}
                {% if variant.available == true %}
                      <li>
                        <input type="radio" value="{{variant.id}}" name="id" {%if variant.id == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id %} checked{% endif %} >
                        <label>{{ variant.title }} for {{ product.price | minus:variant.price | money_with_currency }}</label>
                      </li>
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </fieldset>
            {% else %}
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}">
            {% endif %}
                <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>
                <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" class="inpost-buy w-button" value="Add to Bag →"></input>
          </form>
```

Comment: Why `enctype="multipart/form-data"` …?

Comment: Because I think it's taking into account the variant options as well

Comment: And what does that have to do with the enctype? Are there any file uploads happening via that same form, or what?

Comment: I've removed that bit now - wasn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you are at least sending an id. I think you need a quantity too (you do if you use the cart api) but the straight form post may currently assume 1 if it's not given. I'd add a quantity. If you don't want it to show just use `type=hidden`.

Your second problem is that your code doesn't have a fallback. If a product has options but not available variant you'll be stuck. Generally I use a variable to track whether or not I had a purchasable variant. You can do this a number of ways. I've added a test for that using the product.first_available_variant:

```
{% if product.first_available_variant == true %}
<form ...>
{% if product.options.size > 1 %}
...
<input type="radio" value="{{variant.id}}" name="id" {%if variant.id == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id %} checked{% endif %} >
<label>{{ variant.title }} for {{ product.price | minus:variant.price | money_with_currency }}</label>

...
{% else %}
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}">
{% endif %}

<input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>

</form>
{% else %}
<p>{{ 'no_product_available' | t }}</p> // or just some text if no locale support.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still returns Parameter Missing or Invalid: Required parameter missing or invalid: id

Comment: do you actually have checkboxes? If you use chrome and dev tools what happens when you make preserve the network log -- look at the POST entry and show the headers page. Your post is there below the request and response header sections. Can you paste that here.

Comment: Added the headers from the 'add' / POST sent over the network logs

Comment: You've added the requests and response headers but not the form post which should be below them.

Comment: All the form data says is the following "quantity:1
add:Add to Bag →"

Comment: Then your problem is that you are not formatting your checkboxes properly see my edited answer

Comment: What I was trying to accomplish was - when there is only 1 variant / checkbox don't show any at all. This is when the problems started occurring when adding in the line '{% if product.options.size > 1 %}'

Comment: so you need an else case -- see edited answer again.

Comment: Hi Bknights - Thanks for the help so far, I've updated my question with the code you put in your answer. The only thing is now, products which have more than 1 variant, now don't display any variants whatsoever.